# Blackberry app not appearing on device or simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I've been working on a Blackberry app and it's been running fine on both the simulator and a device but all of a sudden it no longer appears on either.

"Do not display the application icon on the Blackberry home screen" is unchecked. Startup tier it 7, IsSystemModule is false. Nothing has changed here since the first build.

I do see in the simulator console output "app: MyApp not found check if app exists" which is the only reference to my app in the output.

I've cleaned the simulator and I've created a new project with a newly generated app descriptor file with no change so far.

The module files and .cod file appear in the simulator folder, I've tried deleting them and reinstalling.

What else can I do to debug this?

Comment: Do you have a "Main class" with an entry point? (a `public static void main method`) Does it extend `Application` or `UiApplication`? Is the constructor public?

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenarios -

- Are you debugging on the right simulator? If you debug a project compiled against a higher SDK version on a simulator with a lower OS version the app won't show.
- Is there a `main` method in your application at all? Apps without a main method won't show in the app drawer.